# Original function works fine but inside a class as a method does not longer work

Tags: php

i've got this function where i want to format a number, for example, if it's integer like 79, the function returns it as $79,000,000.00.
Otherwise, if it's 79.5, this function returns it as $79,500,000.00.

The function is the following and it's working fine, you  can test it on http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php:

```
function format_bolsa($number)
{
    if(is_int($number))
    {
        echo '<p style="color:#0B3B0B">I am an INT and the number/value before processing is: ',$number,'</p>';
        $number='$'.$number.',000,000.00';
        echo '<p style="color:#0B3B0B">I am an INT and now the formatted number is: ',$number,'</p>';
        return $number;
    }
    else if(is_float($number))
    {
        echo '<p style="color:#0B3B0B">I am a FLOAT and the number/value before processing is: ',$number,'</p>';
        $number_tmp=explode('.',$number);
        $number='$'.$number_tmp[0].','.$number_tmp[1].'00,000.00';
        echo '<p style="color:#0B3B0B">I am a FLOAT and now the formatted number is: ',$number,'</p>';
        return $number;
    }
    echo '<p style="color:#610B0B">Nothing has been done. The number is: ',$bolsa,' but such a value will not be returned!</p>';
}

$number=79;

$number=format_bolsa($number);

echo $number;
```

Nevertheless, when i insert it inside a class like this (becoming a method):

```
public function format_bolsa($number)
{
    if(is_int($number))
    {
        echo '<p style="color:#0B3B0B">I am an INT and the number/value before processing is: ',$number,'</p>';
        $number='$'.$number.',000,000.00';
        echo '<p style="color:#0B3B0B">I am an INT and now the formatted number is: ',$number,'</p>';
        return $number;
    }
    else if(is_float($number))
    {
        echo '<p style="color:#0B3B0B">I am a FLOAT and the number/value before processing is: ',$number,'</p>';
        $number_tmp=explode('.',$number);
        $number='$'.$number_tmp[0].','.$number_tmp[1].'00,000.00';
        echo '<p style="color:#0B3B0B">I am a FLOAT and now the formatted number is: ',$number,'</p>';
        return $number;
    }
    echo '<p style="color:#610B0B">Nothing has been done. The number is: ',$number,' but such a value will not be returned!</p>';
}
```

the now method is not working properly and i get my custom message

> Nothing has been done. The number is:',$number,' but such a value will
>   not be returned!

I call the method like this:

```
$number=self::format_bolsa($number);
```

I don't know why it isn't working. I have inserted other functions like this and they're working fine now as methods.

Anyone can shed some light?

Comment: Since it's not a static function, it should be called as `$this->format_bolsa($number)`. Or you should declare it as a static function.

Comment: Also, where do you set `$bolsa`?

Comment: Edited: Yes, it is $number. Not $bolsa. I am trying with static ... it didn't work :(

Comment: The method is actually called. But i get my custom message where it lets me know that the if's statements were ignored. As a function it works fine. I don't know why.

Comment: what are you passing in?

Comment: @pathros I know the method is being called. But I think it accesses the arguments incorrectly if you don't call it properly.

Comment: @Barmar All right, i'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use [number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)?

```
echo number_format(79 * 1000000, 2);
echo number_format(79.5 * 1000000, 2);
```

Else..here is a working example to help you with your static method:

```
class Test
{
    public static function format_bolsa($number)
    {
        if (is_int($number)) {
            echo 'I\'m an int';
        }
        else if (is_float($number)) {
            echo 'I\'m a float';
        }
    }
}

Test::format_bolsa(79);
Test::format_bolsa(79.5);
```

Now with number_format:

```
class Test
{
    public static function format_bolsa($number)
    {
        return number_format($number * 1000000, 2)
    }
}
```

Also read why static methods are not good: [static considered harmful](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling:

```
$number=$this->format_bolsa($number);
```